# SSH: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh, ansible, ubuntu-14.04

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-ansible-on-ubuntu-18-04) to install Ansible.

At step 2 they ask me to run:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

on the Ansible server in order to copypaste it to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the host.

First, the output of the `cat` command is:

> cat: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory

And as a result, when I try connect from the Ansible server to the host using ssh, I'm getting:

> Permission denied (publickey).

A few things to consider:

1. They asked me to use [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-18-04) in order to set up two Ubuntu 18.04 servers. I did it for the host machine but the Ansible server was existing already on Ubuntu 14.04.
2. I skipped the firewall part, assuming that it would keep all ports accessible.
3. I don't use DigitalOcean but EC2 for both machines (port 22 is enabled in the security group of course).
4. In the "Initial Server Setup with Ubuntu 18.04" guide they had a mistake. They asked me to run an `rsync` command but they forgot to tell me to remove the beginning of the authorized_keys file as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156830/please-login-as-the-user-ubuntu-rather-than-the-user-root/1157525#1157525).
5. I use the same SSH key for both machines and for all users.

Comment: Alternative: You can also use `ssh-copy-id`, if available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is NO firewall issue, because you can connect to ssh.
The user "ubuntu" has no public key. Create it with:

```
 sudo su - ubuntu
 ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Now, cat the file again and place it on the server

Answer (score 0):

[Simple steps](https://jhooq.com/github-permission-denied-publickey/), for mac

1. Create your ssh key
2. Register ssh key in github